# Android application for Gardeners

Tags: discussion

**Precedents:**

Hello there. We are developing an Android (4.0 AKA Ice Cream Sandwich or above) application for gardeners and horticulturists. The application is currently is Beta stage and we need testers with gardening knowledges.

This is the list of features for the moment:

- Own database with more than 8000 plants with detailed information.
- Control various enviroments (like gardens, pots, etc.).
- Current weather conditions card.
- Irrigation information card: last irrigation date, next irrigation date || line charts
- Irrigation prediction based on weather conditions or manual scheduler.
- Favourites plant
- Notifications
- Sync between devices.
- QR Scanner.

Screenshots @ [Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/108875101377248668744/+Botanicayjardines/posts/ae9HhkyUtoH)

**Question:**

Is anyone interested in joining the Beta tester team?

**Note:**

Please take in mind that the application is in spanish, but ready to support other languages. One last thing... I am posting here due to I was asking the correct place in the Chatroom.

Comment: I would love to help, but unfortunately don't have a smartphone. Also I only know English, and some simple Latin. Might be a very helpful app, for those like me who do it all in their brains (the old fashioned way).

Comment: @J.Musser thank you! English is not a problem, it will be translated, but you need an Android or at least a PC Emulator like Genymotion :)

Answer (score 3):

I have an android phone and have been known to design web and mobile applications.  I would be happy to test this out.  I do note that a total of 8000 plants is not comprehensive particularly if it is localized.  You can search on the main site for plant databases.

Edit: you can contact me at: onetimeuse@designworld.com

Comment: Thank you very much! And yes 8.000 plants is not enought... but it is our database (without legal restrictions). We decided to start with most commercial plants (edible, decorative and medicinal). By the way we will update our database in a "not found" count basis. How can I contact you privately?

Comment: @kevinsky Can you please clarify "you can search on the main site for plant databases"?

Comment: This link illustrates that a number of gardeners are looking for a plant database: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=database

Answer (score 2):

Hey I am very interested in this.  I live in the Colombian Andes and speak spanish.  Let me know: trappae19@gmail.com